Lastest Ubuntu update stopped my OS from working properly with my micro
I don't know why or how, but I think my latest Ubuntu update is preventing my OS from working properly with my microphone.
Before the last update, I could use my microphone without any problem.
When I plug a headset, with an integrated microphone, people can listen to a change in the sound that happens when I press the button to cut the headset's microphone, and yet they can't hear me...
Below, there's a picture of what my sound settings looks like.


You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; so we can't know what the last update was.  We also don't know your update procedures (ie. do you update daily? or let updates accrue and thus your last update may have been from the last week (not last for your release), last month etc). As you have access to your machine, and can see logs of what updates occurred; why not provide us details as to what latest update you're referring to. We also don't have basic details such as release so can't currently guess either.
